# Redirection using web.config on wordpress website

Tags: redirect, web-config

I have issue about redirection using web.config . It is word-press website hosted on godaddy.com. Server IIS 7.0  It is window server.

I want redirect from old html page to new wordpress page.
Example:

http://www.dakshadesign.com/Ecommerce_Web_Design.html    to    http://www.dakshadesign.com/ecommerce-website-design-web-development-company-india/

Resloved now

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                       <clear />
                        <rule name="Redirect to dakshadesign.com" stopProcessing="true">
                             <match url="^Ecommerce_Web_Design.html$" />
                             <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.dakshadesign.com/ecommerce-website-design-web-development-company-india" appendQueryString="false" />
                            </rule>
             <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                     </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
             </rule>

             </rules>
         </rewrite>

        </system.webServer>

 </configuration>
```